# Getting an Iterator<Item=str> from an array of &str?

Tags: rust, iteration

I'm trying to abstract a function to take both an instance of [`std::str::Lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Lines.html) and a mocked version for testing purposes, created out of an array of `&str`.

My code (which does work) looks something like this:

```rust
use std::fs;

#[test]
fn test_day_1() {
    let v = ["3", "3", "4", "-2", "-4"].iter().map(|x| *x);
    assert_eq!(day1(v), "334-2-4334-2-4");
}

fn day1_pre() -> String {
    let contents = fs::read_to_string("day1.txt").expect("error reading file");
    day1(contents.lines())
}

fn day1<'a>(lines: impl Iterator<Item = &'a str> + Clone) -> String {
    lines
        .map(|line| {
            let v: Result<i32, _> = line.parse();
            v.expect("could not parse line as integer")
        })
        .cycle()
        .take(10)
        .map(|x| x.to_string())
        .collect()
}
```

However, this code only works because of the weird `.map(|x| *x)` inside the test. If I remove that, I get the following error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::slice::Iter<'_, &str> as Iterator>::Item == &str`
  --> src/lib.rs:6:16
   |
6  |     assert_eq!(day1(v), "334-2-4334-2-4");
   |                ^^^^ expected `str`, found `&str`
...
14 | fn day1<'a>(lines: impl Iterator<Item = &'a str> + Clone) -> String {
   |                                  -------------- required by this bound in `day1`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&str`
              found reference `&&str`
```

I sort of understand the error. [`iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter) returns an `&T`, which in this case yields a `&&str`. What I don't understand is why removing the `map` and replacing `iter` with `into_iter` (i.e. `let v = ["3", "3", "4", "-2", "-4"].into_iter();`) also fails with the same error!

According to [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html#the-three-forms-of-iteration), `into_iter` iterates over `T`, thus it should work here?

While writing this post, I also tried replacing the array with a `Vec` and using `into_iter`, such that the final result is `let v = vec!["3","3","4","-2","-4"].into_iter();` and it worked! However, now I'm even more confused, why would `into_iter` work for `Vec` but not for `Array`?

Comment: [it's complicated](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/66145) use `copied()` or `cloned()` instead for now

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/edition-guide/rust-2021/IntoIterator-for-arrays.html

Comment: actually one can: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=df50f31f8d3dbc685680ff68a8f53bd4 see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/62959

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was announced with the [Rust 1.53 release notes](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/06/17/Rust-1.53.0.html#intoiterator-for-arrays). `IntoIterator` for arrays is new addition that was implemented in 1.53 , but behaves differently in the 2018 and 2021 editions:

> This was not implemented before, due to backwards compatibility problems. Because `IntoIterator` was already implemented for references to arrays, `array.into_iter()` already compiled in earlier versions, resolving to `(&array).into_iter()`.

> As of this release, arrays implement IntoIterator with a small workaround to avoid breaking code. The compiler will continue to resolve `array.into_iter()` to **`(&array).into_iter()`**, as if the trait implementation does not exist. This only applies to the `.into_iter()` method call syntax, and does not affect any other syntax such as `for e in [1, 2, 3]`, `iter.zip([1, 2, 3])` or `IntoIterator::into_iter([1, 2, 3])`, which all compile fine.

> Since this special case for `.into_iter()` is only required to avoid breaking existing code, it is removed in the new edition, Rust 2021, which will be released later this year. See the edition announcement for more information.

Therefore your code will [compile just fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6ce60a150abe43048400f5795aaab153) with Rust 2021

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could just take an iterator of anything that can be taken as a reference into a str (any `&&&&&..&str` should):

```rust
fn day1<T>(lines: impl Iterator<Item = T> + Clone) -> String where T : AsRef<str>{
    lines
        .map(|line| {
            let v: Result<i32, _> = line.as_ref().parse();
            v.expect("could not parse line as integer")
        })
        .cycle()
        .take(10)
        .map(|x| x.to_string())
        .collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=139bbd52e61a047e71e03f0260515774)

And why would `into_iter` work for a `Vec` and not a slice, well, if you read the current warning when using `into_iter`:

```
warning: this method call currently resolves to `<&[T; N] as IntoIterator>::into_iter` (due to autoref coercions), but that might change in the future when `IntoIterator` impls for arrays are added.
 --> src/lib.rs:5:41
  |
5 |     let v = ["3", "3", "4", "-2", "-4"].into_iter();
  |                                         ^^^^^^^^^ help: use `.iter()` instead of `.into_iter()` to avoid ambiguity: `iter`
  |
  = note: `#[warn(array_into_iter)]` on by default
  = warning: this was previously accepted by the compiler but is being phased out; it will become a hard error in a future release!
  = note: for more information, see issue #66145 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/66145>
```

Follow to the [issue link](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/66145) where there is a good explanation.
Keypoint is:

> `[1, 2, 3].into_iter().for_each(|n| { *n; });` Currently this works,
> as into_iter returns an iterator over references to the array's
> values, meaning that n is indeed &{integer} and can be dereferenced.